# Pubnub presence event firing continuously

Tags: angularjs, pubnub

I am using pubnub js sdk with pubnub's angular wrapper.  I have been using the publish & subscribe methods for some time, and now it's time to integrate presence.

Problem is, when I follow the sample, the presence event fires continuously.

Seems to be coming from the pubnub.min.js rather than the angular wrapper.

```
$rootScope.$on(PubNub.ngPrsEv(self.channel), function (event, payload) {
                    console.log('Presence', payload);
                    self.users = PubNub.ngHereNow({ channel: self.channel });
                    console.log('Here now');
                });
```

The event object being passed has a message of "OK", with the collection of uuids.  Any ideas why this is happening?

G

Answer (score 1):

ngHereNow, as all pubnub calls, is asynchronoues and uses callbacks to pass results back to the caller.

```
PubNub.ngHereNow({ channel: <somechannel>, callback: function(cb){ //process results"}});
```

This is really a wrapper around the equivalent here_now call in the pubnub Javascript SDK, and works the same way. You can review the documentation for the javascript call:

https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference#here_now